# Appending selected dropdown prefix to url in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following form that submits a phone number from a form using ajax. I am trying to append the selected country code from the dropdown to the query string.

This gives me the correct URL with the phone number:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/textMessage/' + phone,
    method: "GET",
    success: function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
});
```

I want to prefix the selected country code from this form:

```
<button id="label" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">+1 <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#" id="1">US: +1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="44">UK: +44</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

to the url. So the URL should appear as `domain.com/textMessage/12122225555`

I tried pulling the selected option using `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`, and prepending it like so: url: `'/textMessage/' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + phone,`
but this isn't working.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/1a8r5gmv/4/)

Comment: fiddle works for me. What are you seeing in browser console for the url?

Comment: @charlietfl, it's working with just the phone number, but not with the country code prefixed to the url. It's not adding the "1" or "44" to the beginning of the phone number entered.

Comment: there's no code in the fiddle to do that

Comment: @charlietfl, I put it in the end of the question, so the working copy can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the id (or class if you would like to) to your area code text like:

```
<button id="label" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span id="areaCode">+1</span> 
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Than you can get the area code by:

```
var areaCode = $('#areaCode').text();
```

and to prepend it infront of your phone number you can do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/textMessage/' + areaCode + phone,
```

also need to modify the area code click event as:

```
$("#1, #44").click(function (e) {
    $("#label").html('<span id="areaCode">+' + $(this).attr("id") + '</span> <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Also if you want to get rid of the '+' sign, then your `areaCode` would be:

```
var areaCode = $('#areaCode').text().replace('+','');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1a8r5gmv/7/